# Simplex Method with Nontrivial Initial Solution

Tags: linear-programming

I have a linear program with the following tableaux:

\begin{array}{crrrrrr|l}
               & x_1 & x_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & P &   rhs     \\ \hline
            &   67&  126&   52&   36&   -7&    0&  988\\
            &  -24&  -46&  -19&  -14&    3&    0& -358 \\
            &   -9&  -17&   -7&   -5&    1&    0& -133\\ \hline
            &   -40 &   -30 &   0   &   0 &   0 &   1 &         0 \\ \hline
  \end{array}

where I want to maximize $P$. I want to apply the simplex method starting from the initial solution $(x_1,x_2,s_1,s_2,s_3)=(8,0,8,1,0)$, but I'm confused about how to pivot when nearly all elements of the matrix are nonzero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make $x_1$, $s_1$, and $s_2$ basic first. To achieve this you can execute a sequence of pivots such that the matrix corresponding to these columns is the identity matrix $I$. This is the same process used in Gaussian elimination to produce a [reduced row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form). After that continue with Phase II of the Simplex method.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!